# Fire child page window Select onchange event from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have parent .aspx page where i am calling a 3 party website and filling the form.

i am facing the problem in firing the event of child page event.

```
 Var MyWeb = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");

 var controlCat = MyWeb.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbCategory");
                if (controlCat != null) {
                    controlCat.value = subCat;
                    $(controlCat).trigger("change");
```

Comment: $(controlCat).trigger("change"); part is not firing...

Comment: Is the code going into the if statement - have you verified whether `controlCat` is null or empty, what listener is attached to the `change` event?

Comment: Yes it is going. and yes the event is attached.

Comment: The browser i am opening child. its not under my development. i supposed just to transfer data to that form by analyze what event what value.